# Ayuda con: almacenar en un arreglo String palabras hasta que encuentre un espacio. (Java)

Tags: java

Mi pregunta es acerca de: 
De acuerdo a la cadena que ingreso, cada vez que encuentra un espacio, que almacene la palabra en un arreglo String, es un ejercicio en en java.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YJRa9.jpg]

Este es el codigo que solo me imprime con un salto de línea cada que encuentra un espacio

```
public static void escribir() {
    System.out.print("Ingrese una cadena: ");
    cadena = sc.nextLine();
}

public static void imprimir() {
    for (int i = 0; i < cadena.length(); i++) {
        letra[i] = cadena.charAt(i);
        if (letra[i] == ' ') {
            System.out.print("\n");
        }
        System.out.print(letra[i]);;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    escribir();
    imprimir();
    sc.close();
}
```

}

Comment: @JulioDávilaCerrón gracias Julio, como te comentaba L.Ronquillo, en este caso puedes usar el método split(), gracias por agregar información a tu pregunta, de esta forma la comunidad pueda ayudarte de una mejor manera :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En este caso puedes usar el método [split()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-) para crear un array de elementos a partir del token de separación de los mismos que en este caso sería el espacio en blanco, para esto puedes usar la como REGEX "\s+".

```
public static void imprimir() {  

    //separa por espacios y crea array
    String palabras[] = cadena.split("\\s+"); 

    //Imprime elementos en array

     for (String palabra : palabras){
        System.out.print(palabra+"\n");
     }


}
```

De esta forma imprimirá:

```
Somos
libres,
seamoslo
siempre
```

Comment: Gracias @Elenasys, completaré lo restante